# What type of tree structure or existing app is best to fully index a set of documents to find any string of characters up to say 300 in length

Tags: indexing, text, tree, full-text-search

Longer Title:
What **type of tree** structure or existing app would be best to fully index a set of documents to find (using the tree to search) any string of characters up to say 300 in length.

It should return the set of documents (by ID) and the offset to start of string(s)
**==== I would like to use it to find: ====**

- longest strings with that are duplicated more than once.
- most common strings in a document, set of documents, all documents
- strings that have the Max(length_of_string * num_of_duplicates).
- --- and stuff like that...

Not tried yet. Don't know where to begin.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please add the tag of the language you are using for this work, and also a try, a piece of code, of what you have done. Else, we cannot help you.